# Trying to create a row with 4 cells

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to create a row with 4 cells and I don't know why its not working.

I have created a parent `row` and 4 children.

```
<div className='row'>
                <div className='col-1-of-4'>
                    hi
                </div>
                <div className='col-1-of-4'>
                    hi
                </div>
                <div className='col-1-of-4'>
                    hi
                </div>
                <div className='col-1-of-4'>
                    hi
                </div>
            </div>
```

(Ignore the className for class, as I am using react)

and the css properties are:

```
[class^="col-"] {
        float: left;
        &:not(:last-child) {
            margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
        }  
    }

.col-1-of-4 {
    width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 4);
}
```

What it does is, calculates total width, and then subtracts the margin and then divides by 4. 
Technically it should work and I should be able to see 4 cells in a row.
But the result I get is, 3 cells in a row and the fourth one on the next line.

the result should be something like this

`hi         hi         hi         hi`

but the actual result is

`hi         hi         hi
 hi`

Here is the working code
https://codepen.io/sarmad1995/pen/REYXBV?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't divide the margin inside your calculation. It should be outside or will you will remove less than the margin set for each element. You are setting `X` margin and only removing `X/4` so each element will take `25% - X/4 + X` (the last one `25% - X/4`)  as a space thus the total will be `100% + 2X` which bigger than `100%`.

```
.col-1-of-4 {
    width: calc(100% / 4  - #{$gutter-horizontal});
}
```

```css
.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.row [class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
}
.row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}
.row .col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc(100%  / 4 - 6rem);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
  hi
  </div>
</div>
```

And in case you need a space between behavior (which is what you want) you can do like this:

```
.col-1-of-4 {
    width: calc(100% / 4  - 3*#{$gutter-horizontal}/4);
}
```

That you can also write like this:

```
.col-1-of-4 {
     width: calc((100% - 3*#{$gutter-horizontal})/4);
 }
```

You need to remove the 3 margins (defined for the first 3 elements) from the total width then divide by 4:

```css
.row {
  max-width: 114rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.row [class^="col-"] {
  float: left;
}
.row [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}
.row .col-1-of-4 {
  width: calc(100%  / 4 - 3*6rem/4);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
   hi
  </div>
  <div class='col-1-of-4'>
  hi
  </div>
</div>
```

*You should apply the same logic for all your other classes*

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you explain a bit why did it remove less margin?

Comment: @Sarmad because for each element you set X margin and you remove X/4 margin which is less

Comment: Understood, this means i need to change my all calculations inside grid.

Comment: @Sarmad yes exactly

Comment: @Sarmad I added more details ;)

Comment: Thank you so much :). I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codepen example, you are setting a `margin-right`.

```
[class^="col-"] {
    float: left;
    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
    }  
}
```

Removing this gives you the four columns as described.

*Please in future include all relevant code to your question.*

Comment: I dont want to remove it, the margin-right property is set to only first 3 cells, and when calculating the width of the cells, i subtract it.

Comment: I have updated my codepen with background color, as you can margin-right has nothing to do with this as i clearly subtract it inside calc function. I want that margin between the cells,